# jQuery event handler only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple web-based lookup utility for a board game called Rail Baron. There are two text inputs that are wired up to jQuery autoComplete, which appears to be working great. On any change event from the inputs, a dollar amount is displayed -- representing the payoff for a trip between two cities.

**The `change()` event handler is called in Firefox, but not other browsers.** Doesn't work in IE so I don't think this is a webkit issue. Looking for a work-around or to understand why this is happening. **Full application available at http://paislee.net/railbaron. Thanks!**

Dependencies, loaded in `<head>`:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Relevant markup:

```
<form id="payoffForm" action="#">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <strong>Payoff Lookup</strong>
                    </legend>
                    <label for="from">From:</label>
                    <input id="from" type="text">
                    <label for="to">To:</label>
                    <input id="to" type="text">
                    <div id="result">$</div>
                </fieldset>             
            </form>
```

My JavaScript, loaded just before closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var chart; // small csv file in memory

            // this updates the dollar amount displayed
            function updatePayoff() {

                var result;
                var from = $("#from").val();
                var to = $("#to").val();

                var from_i = chart[0].indexOf(from);
                var to_i = chart[0].indexOf(to);
                result = chart[to_i + 1][from_i] * 1000;

                $("#result").html( result ? "$" + result : "$");

            }

            // attach event handlers
            $("#from").change(function() {
                updatePayoff();
            });

            $("#to").change(function() {
                updatePayoff();
            });

            // entry point
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "./payoffs.csv",
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(result) {
                        chart = CSVToArray(result);
                        $("#from").autocomplete({
                            source : chart[0]
                        });
                        $("#to").autocomplete({
                            source : chart[0]
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            // parsing my csv file into autocomplete array
            function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
                // ..implementation..
            }

</script>
```

**Full application available at http://paislee.net/railbaron. Thanks!**

Comment: I might add that console isn't showing any script errors.

Comment: @Sudhir my bad its on change().

Comment: did you try alerting something or colsole.log("someting") on change event to see if anything comes up..

Comment: @Sudhir yep. verified that the handler is not being fired, using an alert statement.

Comment: The alert seems to be coming up for me for IE9 as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the jQuery UI Autocomplete's [`select`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-select) callback.  This is completely untested, but try this:

```
        /* REMOVE
        $("#from").change(function() {
            updatePayoff();
        });

        $("#to").change(function() {
            updatePayoff();
        });
        */

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "./payoffs.csv",
                cache : false,
                success : function(result) {
                    chart = CSVToArray(result);
                    $("#from").autocomplete({
                        source : chart[0],
                        select: function() {
                            updatePayoff();
                        }
                    });
                    $("#to").autocomplete({
                        source : chart[0],
                        select: function() {
                            updatePayoff();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: This fixed it. Still trying to understand why change() is failing. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that most browsers don't recognize the "change" event in a text field. Through personal experience, `change` is usually used in dropdowns, radios, and checkboxes... not text fields.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `input` tags are not closed.

```
<input id="to" type="text">
```

I believe this is invalid for some (all?) doctypes - try closing them and see if that fixes things

```
<input id="to" type="text" />
```

It also looks like your script tag is **outside** of your body, which I don't think is valid.  Try moving it to the **end** of your body, but still inside.

Comment: I gave a link to the app..is it better SO practice to post all markup here?

Comment: Nice catch, didn't fix it tho.

Comment: @paislee - I think I have one more idea before my reservoir runs dry - see my edit

Comment: Adam, the `/>` "closing" is only required for some doctypes. `<input>` is not necessarily wrong. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.2

Comment: @JaredFarrish - thanks.  How invalid is it to have free-standing script tags, outside your body?

Comment: Wow. I went public with some shabby markup. Appreciate the help, Ayman Safadi nailed it.

Comment: @paislee - glad you got your answer from somewhere :)

Comment: [The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) seem to suggest that the `script` tag may only be placed in the `body` and `head` tags. Outside of that is inconsistent, but if the doctype is quirksmode due to the overall page's evaluation, I suppose it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very similar to a problem that I had when tweaking the dom and running click / change handlers.  For me, the `.on()` [functionality](http://api.jquery.com/on/) fixed the problem.  FYI, `.on()` is the newer version of `.live()`